# What is the lifetime of the range-init in a range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, language-lawyer, lifetime

In the latest C++ standard it implies that:

```
for (foo : bar)
    baz;
```

is equivilant to:

```
{
    auto && r = bar;
    for ( auto it = r.begin(), end = r.end(); it != end; ++it )
    {
        foo = *it;
        baz;
    }
}
```

When bar in the above is a function call that returns a collection, eg:

```
vector<string> boo();
```

ie

```
for (auto bo : boo())
    ...
```

Doesn't the line become:

```
auto&& r = boo();
...
```

And so the temporary return value of `boo()` is destroyed at the end of the statement `auto&& r = boo()`, and then r is a hanging reference at the entry of the loop. Is this reasoning correct?  If not, why not?

Comment: First of all, `vector<string> boo();` does NOT declare an object. It declares a function. Second, I don't understand your question.

Comment: Yes "vector<string> boo()" is the signature of an example function that returns a collection.  The function is then called in the line below.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Is this reasoning correct? If not, why not?

It is correct up until this point:

> And so the temporary return value of boo() is destroyed at the end of the statement "auto&&r=boo()" [...]

Binding a temporary to a reference extends its lifetime to be that of the reference. So the temporary lasts for the whole loop (that's also why there is an extra set of `{}` around the whole construct: to correctly limit the lifetime of that temporary).

This is according to paragraph 5 of §12.2 of the C++ standard:

> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary. The
>   temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the
>   complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound
>   persists for the lifetime of the reference except:
>
> [various exceptions that don't apply here]

This is an interesting property that allows abusing the ranged-for loop for non-rangey things: http://ideone.com/QAXNf

Answer (score 9):

The reasoning is not correct because `boo` returns a temporary object by value. Binding this temporary object to a reference implies that the lifetime of the temporary is extended. Standard quote (§ 12.2/5):

> […] The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference […]

The reasoning would be correct if `boo` returned a reference. An example for an expression returning a reference to a temporary is `string("a") += string("b")`; using this value in a range-based `for` loop gives rise to undefined behavior.