# temporary object in range-based for

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I know that in general the life time of a temporary in a range-based `for` loop is extended to the whole loop (I've read [C++11: The range-based for statement: "range-init" lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657708/c11-the-range-based-for-statement-range-init-lifetime)). Therefore doing stuff like this is generally OK:

```
for (auto &thingy : func_that_returns_eg_a_vector())
  std::cout << thingy;
```

Now I'm stumbling about memory issues when I try to do something I thought to be similar with Qt's `QList` container:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QList>

int main() {
  for (auto i : QList<int>{} << 1 << 2 << 3)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that valgrind shows invalid memory access somewhere inside the `QList` class. However, modifying the example so that the list is stored in variable provides a correct result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QList>

int main() {
  auto things = QList<int>{} << 1 << 2 << 3;
  for (auto i : things)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Now my question is: am I doing something dumb in the first case resulting in e.g. undefined behaviour (I don't have enough experience reading the C++ standard in order to answer this for myself)? Or is this an issue with how I use `QList`, or how `QList` is implemented?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're using C++11, [you could use initialization list instead](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qlist.html#QList-3). This will pass valgrind:

```
int main() {
  for (auto i : QList<int>{1, 2, 3})
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

---

The problem is not totally related to range-based for or even C++11.  The following code demonstrates the same problem:

```
QList<int>& things = QList<int>() << 1;
things.end();
```

or:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int* x;

    S() { x = NULL; }
    ~S() { delete x; }

    S& foo(int y) {
        x = new int(y);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    S& things = S().foo(2);
    std::cout << *things.x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The invalid read is because the temporary object from the expression `S()` (or `QList<int>{}`) is destructed after the declaration (following C++03 and C++11 §12.2/5), because the compiler has no idea that the method `foo()` (or `operator<<`) will return that temporary object. So you are now refering to content of freed memory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. And stupid me, of course I should have used an initialization list in the first place -- I somehow simply didn't think about it. Probably due to Qt's examples always using `<<` for similar cases.

Comment: Ah well, looks like C++11 support is only available in Qt 4.8 and later. But for cases such as this I can easily use the containers from the standard library instead.

Comment: Could this problem be circumvented by casting to `QList<int> const&` (i.e. writing `for (auto i : static_cast<QList<int> const&>(QList<int>{} << 1 << 2 << 3))`)? That way, it would be bound to a const reference in the `for` loop initialisation, if I read §6.5.4 correctly, and that in turn would extend the temporary’s life-time to the scope of the loop.

Comment: I cannot comment on the validity but valgrind says `no, you cannot` :)

Comment: The _real_ problem here is `QList`'s `operator<<` return type (non-const lvalue reference). `for (auto i : QList<int>{})` without using `<<` is fine because the `QList` instance is an rvalue and will play nice with the semantics of `auto&&`.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler can't possibly know that the reference that is the result of three calls to `operator <<` is bound to the temporary object `QList<int>{}`, so the life of the temporary is not extended.  The compiler does not know (and can't be expected to know) anything about the return value of a function, except its type.  If it's a reference, it doesn't know what it may bind to.  I'm pretty sure that, in order for the life-extending rule to apply, the binding has to be direct.

This should work because the list is no longer a temporary:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QList>

int main() {
  auto things = QList<int>{};
  for (auto i : things << 1 << 2 << 3)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And this should work because the binding is direct, so the rule can apply:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QList>

int main() {
  for (auto i : QList<int>{1, 2, 3})
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```