# Preventing users from creating unnamed instances of a class

Tags: c++, c++17, raii

For many **RAII "guard"** classes, being instantiated as anonymous variables does not make sense at all:

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex>{some_mutex};
    // Does not protect the scope!
    // The unnamed instance is immediately destroyed.
}
```

```
{
    scope_guard{[]{ cleanup(); }};
    // `cleanup()` is executed immediately!
    // The unnamed instance is immediately destroyed.
}
```

From [this article](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/814-anonymous-variables-and-objects/):

> Anonymous variables in C++ have “expression scope”, meaning they are destroyed at the end of the expression in which they are created.

---

**Is there any way to prevent the user from instantiating them without a name?** *("Prevent" may be too strong - "making it very difficult" is also acceptable).*

I can think of two possible workarounds, but they introduce syntactical overhead in the use of the class:

1. Hide the class in a `detail` namespace and provide a macro.

   ```
   namespace detail
   {
       class my_guard { /* ... */ };
   };

   #define SOME_LIB_MY_GUARD(...) \
       detail::my_guard MY_GUARD_UNIQUE_NAME(__LINE__) {__VA_ARGS__}
   ```

   This works, but is *hackish*.
2. Only allow the user to use the guard  through an higher-order function.

   ```
   template <typename TArgTuple, typename TF>
   decltype(auto) with_guard(TArgTuple&& guardCtorArgs, TF&& f)
   {
       make_from_tuple<detail::my_guard>(std::forward<TArgTuple>(guardCtorArgs));
       f();
   }
   ```

   Usage:

   ```
   with_guard(std::forward_as_tuple(some_mutex), [&]
   {
       // ...
   });
   ```

   This workaround does not work when the initialization of the guard class has "fluent" syntax:

   ```
   {
       auto _ = guard_creator()
                    .some_setting(1)
                    .some_setting(2)
                    .create();
   }
   ```

Is there any better alternative? I have access to C++17 features.

Comment: I think you're asking in the wrong direction. C++ developers should understand why `lock_guard` exists and why should it stay alive as long as the scope it protects stands. trying to enforce this via API or internal implementation is just redundant..

Comment: @Danh: the other question's answer is my "macro" workaround. Would you consider reopening this question if I make it more obvious that I'm looking for a non-macro-based solution?

@David: for the `lock_guard` example, I agree. I was working on some non-allocation async chain generation with "fluent" syntax though, where it's very natural to have anonymous chains. But you still need a name, otherwise the storage for the chain dies too quickly. It's not as obvious as the `lock_guard`, and I'd like to prevent this mistake.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo There're other answers in that question. And, IMHO, if we can centralize all discussion about this in one place, it's better. Anyway, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16192104/4115625) looks very interesting

Comment: @VittorioRomeo so basically, you work on a stack-allocated version of `std::async` + `future::then`?

Comment: This one also related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914861/disallowing-creation-of-the-temporary-objects

Comment: "being instantiated as anonymous variables does not make sense at all" except when the result is bound to a reference and lifetime-extended. That's about the only way you can write a `make_lock_guard` before C++17. One possibility is to force the use of a `make_` function and then mark it `[[nodiscard]]`.

Comment: Does not answer this question, but clang-tidy has a check that looks for this pattern which already helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only sensible way I think about is to make the user pass the result of `guard_creator::create` to some `guard_activator` which takes a lvalue-reference as a parameter.

this way, the user of the class has no way but either create the object with a name (the sane option that most developers will do), or `new` it then dereference (insane options)

for example, you said in the comments you work on a non allocating asynchronous chain creator. I can think on an API which looks like this:

```
auto token = monad_creator().then([]{...}).then([]{...}).then([]{...}).create();
launch_async_monad(token); //gets token as Token&, the user has no way BUT create this object with a name
```

Comment: MSVC++ sends her regards

Comment: @Danh they fixed that glitch a long time ago

Comment: http://rextester.com/DALS87730 is compiled successful with and without `/Za`. 1900 indicates this is VS2015

Comment: @Danh You can compile with /we4239 to treat that extension as error

Comment: This looks very promising for my particular situation. I'll try it out ASAP - thanks

Comment: If you change it to an rvalue-reference wouldn't it also work? But allow you to call a function where the guard-object is active during the function call. That contradicts the requirement my in the question (it is an unnamed object) - but the guard is still active when needed.

Comment: @HansOlsson rvalue reference can catch temporeries.

Comment: Yes, they can temporarily catch temporaries. But does that cause a specific problem? It lives during the time the function is called. However, I understand if you want to call two functions and want the lock to active for both it will not work - and for that reason lvalue-reference could be better. A user can make the same error by having two separate scopes with guard and function call; but that seems odd.

Answer (score 3):

If have access to the full potential of C++17, you can expand the idea of using a static factory function into something usefull: guarantied copy elision makes the static factory function possible even for non-movable classes, and the [[nodiscard]] attributes prompts the compiler to issue a warning if the return value is ignored.

```cpp
class [[nodiscard]] Guard {
  public:
    Guard(Guard& other) = delete;
    ~Guard() { /* do sth. with _ptr */ }
    static Guard create(void* ptr) { return Guard(ptr); }
  private:
    Guard(void* ptr) : _ptr(ptr) {}
    void* _ptr;
};

int main(int, char**) {
  Guard::create(nullptr);
  //auto g = Guard::create(nullptr);
}
```

[Compile in Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dsvF_e)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extensible lint tool such as Vera++ https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Home it lets you lint your code, you can create new rules using Python or tcl (I prefer Python)

A possible flow would be - after each commit, your CI system (e.g Jenkins) will run a job that executes Vera++ and validate such oversights, upon a failure a mail would be issued to the committer.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to prevent a class from being instantiated is by making its constructor `private`. To actually get one of the desired instances, you call a `static` method, which returns a reference to a constructed object.

```
class Me {
public:
    static Me &MakeMe() { return Me(); }
private:
    Me();
}; // Me
```

This doesn't help of course - but it'd probably make the programmer pause!

```
int main() {
    Me(); // Invalid
    Me m; // Invalid
    Me::MakeMe(); // Valid - but who'd write that?
    Me m = Me::MakeMe();
} // main()
```

I know this *isn't* a direct analog to the `Guard` instances that you describe - but maybe you could adapt the concept?

Comment: I don't think this should even compile; you're binding an rvalue to an lvalue reference.