# What is wrong with std::lock_guard

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have simple code: first thread pushes `std::strings` to the `std::list`, and second thread pops `std::strings` from this `std::list`. All `std::list`s operations are protected with `std::mutex m`. This code permanently prints error to console: `"Error: lst.begin() == lst.end()"`.

If I replace `std::lock_guard` with construction `m.lock()` and `m.unlock()` the code begins work correctly. What is wrong with `std::lock_guard`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <list>
#include <string>

std::mutex m;
std::list<std::string> lst;

void f2()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> { m };
        lst.push_back(std::to_string(i));
    }

    m.lock();
    lst.push_back("-1"); // last list's element
    m.unlock();
}

void f1()
{
    std::string str;

    while (true)
    {
        m.lock();
        if (!lst.empty())
        {
            if (lst.begin() == lst.end())
            {
                std::cerr << "Error: lst.begin() == lst.end()" << std::endl;
            }
            str = lst.front();
            lst.pop_front();
            m.unlock();
            if (str == "-1")
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m.unlock();
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }
}

// tested in MSVS2017
int main()
{
    std::thread tf2{ f2 };
    f1();
    tf2.join();
}
```

Comment: [P0577](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0577r1.pdf) proposes to avoid this by repurposing the `register` keyword to mean 'associate the following anonymous object(s) with this entire scope'.

Answer (score 22):

You did not obey [CppCoreGuidelines CP.44: Remember to name your lock_guards and unique_locks](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rconc-name) :).

In

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> { m };
    lst.push_back(std::to_string(i));
}
```

you are only creating a temporary `std::lock_guard` object which is created and destroyed immediately. You need to name the object like in

```
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg{ m };
    lst.push_back(std::to_string(i));
}
```

so that the lock guard lives until the end of the block.

And as you already recognized ([CppCoreGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#to-do-unclassified-proto-rules)):

> Use RAII lock guards (lock_guard, unique_lock, shared_lock), never call mutex.lock and mutex.unlock directly (RAII)

If you are using Microsoft Visual Studio, I recommend using the code analysis and activating at least the *Microsoft Native Recommended Rules*. If you do this you will get a compiler analysis warning.

> warning C26441: Guard objects must be named (cp.44).

Comment: @Igorrr37 I updated my answer, this is even a guideline in the CppCoreGuidelines. If my answer worked for you, it would be nice if you accept it.

Comment: [This is such an easy mistake to make, unfortunately.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16189942/560648)

Comment: There is actually a good reason to have unnamed temporary `lock_guard`s and `unique_lock`s: If only a single expression needs to execute with the lock held: `std::lock_guard{m}, do_locked(a,b,c);`.

Comment: @Deduplicator I question how useful it really is, merely so you can fit everything on one line, while having unusual syntax and requiring a rewrite if you want something else covered by the lock (which can be forgotten and leave you with an immediately dying lock as in the OP, is hostile to version control diffing, etc.).

Comment: It's a shame you can't `[[nodiscard]]` a constructor.

Comment: @RaymondChen Starting with C++20 `[[nodiscard]]` can be used on constructors :). But it looks like it is not yet used on `unique_lock` constructor :(.