# Is there a short way to write for i in range(100) in C++?

Tags: c++, initializer-list

If I got that right I can use this to iterate over a fixed range:

```c
for(int i: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
    do_sth(i);
```

And this is the same thing:

```c
vector<int> v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for(int i: v)
    do_sth(i);
```

But what if I want to iterate over the range of 1, ..., 100 and already know that at compile time? 
What is the most beautiful way to do that?
What the most efficient?
What the shortest?

Edit: of course I could write a regular for loop, but the actual use case would involve more complicated content than `int`s.

I just oversimplified the example a bit.

Comment: Or you could use a macro, but they're evil, so yeah.

Comment: Actually, you could generate the range at compile time using template recursion, but that only works for POD types, and you'd be limited by the maximum template recursion the compiler allows

Comment: @black_puppydog Your edit changes the question more than you might think. What is the real situation?

Comment: @BoBTFish I actually wanted to iterate over a predefined list/vector of STL objects, but I think I'll just write a simple iterator that does the job since actually it fits better.
I guess I was hoping a little for some automagic but I think with C++ I won't get that :D sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please look at the solution of Khurshid Normuradov at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483706/range-based-loop-c11-for-rangel-r/18484480#18484480

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "easily" write a for-range-compatible class that represents an integer range. You just have to write the iterators for it.

Or you can use [Boost.Range's `counting_range`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html), which is exactly that.

Answer (score 16):

```
for( int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i )
{
    do_sth( i );
}
```

?

Comment: Simple is beautiful. ;-)

Comment: Andrew Koenig has much to say on the joys of asymmetric bounds! [Part 1](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/asymmetric-bounds-part-1-what-are-they/240001666). But yes, just do this.

Comment: @black_puppydog - this totally changes the situation. That just became absolutely different question.

Comment: +1 - I prefer the more verbose readability of this simple code over complicated short constructs that are not widely known (yet). This is readable by even the most novice C++ programmer.

Comment: @KirilKirov agreed, things change pretty quickly here, experimenting with the code for the next homework assignment and different algorithms.
on a small meta: how to proceed? close question?

Comment: @black_puppydog - no, no, leave it like this, as you have found your answer here.

Comment: Original answer mentions that this could be any other types besides int. `for` loop is good for numbers only.

Comment: @kworr - first of all, this doesn't make my answer incorrect to deserve a down-vote. And second - if you see more carefully, you'll see, that the note about the `for` is an edit (which was done after I posted my answer).

Answer (score 4):

If you really want it in a container, you can fill a container using the [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) function. Otherwise use a normal `for` loop.

Comment: @CharlesSalvia: The question asks about beauty, not just efficiency. `iota` is a beautiful word.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - yeah, really beautiful word :D Anyway - it also asks about "shortest" and "most efficient" ways

Comment: @MikeSeymour I like the word too, especially since if translated to Swedish it's "jota" which can be used as "inte ett jota" which means "absolutely nothing".

Answer (score 1):

Use a range-for with a function template:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <int... Is>
    struct index { };

    template <int N, int... Is>
    struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> { };

    template <int... Is>
    struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : index<Is...> { };
}

template <int... Is>
std::array<int, sizeof...(Is)> range(detail::index<Is...>)
{
    return {{ Is... }};
}

template <int N>
std::array<int, N> range()
{
    return range(detail::gen_seq<N>{});
}
```

Example:

```
for (auto i : range<5>())
{
    do_sth(i);
}
```

Comment: Especially useful for ranges like 1..100000 and such.

Comment: A no go for iterating from first to last integer.

Comment: @DieterLücking I'm sure someone will figure out how to do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Example of an iterator-based technique, as Sebastian Redl mentioned:

```
class range {
public:
    struct rangeIt{
        rangeIt(int v) : _v(v){}
        int operator*()const{return _v;}
        void operator++(){_v++;}
        bool operator!=(const rangeIt & other)const{ return _v != other._v;}
    private:
        int _v;
    };
    range(int a, int b):_a(a),_b(b){}
    rangeIt begin() const { return rangeIt(_a); }
    rangeIt end() const { return rangeIt(_b); }
private:
    int _a, _b;
};
```

Then it can be used like this:

```
for(int i : range(0, 100)) {
  printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<int> operator"" _r(const char* text, const size_t)
{
    string txt(text);

    auto delim  = txt.find('-');
    auto first  = txt.substr( 0, delim);
    auto second = txt.substr(delim + 1);

    int lower = stoi(first);
    int upper = stoi(second);

    vector<int> rval(upper - lower);

    generate(rval.begin(), rval.end(), [&]{ return lower++; } );

    return rval;
}

int main() 
{
    for(auto& el : "10-100"_r)
        cout<<el<<"\n";
}
```

Big runtime overhead, error prone ( mainly my implementation )... just the way I like it !

But it does solve the problem and even has a not-that-ugly syntax :)